# Is there a way to forward declare an enum class which is inside a structure that is also forward declared?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, declaration, forward-declaration

I've searched about this but couldn't come up with any idea nor find anything.

I have a forward declared `struct Edge` and a `namespace`, where i use an `enum class` as a parameter from the `struct Edge` in a function :

```
struct Edge;
namespace validation { bool is_color_valid(const Edge::Color& color){;} }

struct Edge { enum class Color { Gray, Green, Blue, Yellow, Red }; }
```

I'm getting **"Incomplete type 'Edge' named in nested name specifier"** error in function declaration, exactly where `const Edge::Color& color` is.

So I guess i need to forward declare this `enum class` which is nested inside a `struct` so that the compiler should understand that actually the structure is not incomplete. I don't want to relocate the namespace. Is this possible?

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You can't forward declare *anything* that is defined inside a structure. You need to rethink your code. For instance, why does the `Color` type depend on `Edge` at all?

Comment: @molbdnilo perhaps not real colors but the "colors" in edge coloring of graph theory were meant there.

Comment: nesting classes is a form of encapsulation rather than to just structure the code. If `Edge` and `Color` are closely related you can put them in a namespace

Comment: @ÖöTiib yes, exactly.

Comment: @molbdnilo The code is actually more complex and i have many structures but the `Edge` is the only one, elements of which should be colored, so I wanted to nest it inside `struct Edge` and that's why i prefer not to move anything

Comment: A bad idea is a bad idea, even if you feel that it's something you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can't partially declare a class. As a workaround, you can take your enum out and prefix its name, then create a shorter typedef for it within the definition of your class:

```cpp
enum class EdgeColor {};
struct Edge;
bool is_color_valid(EdgeColor);

struct Edge { using Color = EdgeColor; };
bool is_color_valid(Edge::Color) { return true; }
```